# Multiple GROUP_CONCAT in single select statement

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

I have a query that is similar to the below

```
SELECT s.ip, 
    t.name AS 'typeName', 
    e.name AS 'envName',
    i.name,
    s.computerName
    #ap.name
    #GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT i.name ORDER BY i.name ASC SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS instances
    #GROUP_CONCAT(ap.name ORDER BY ap.name ASC SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS AppPool
FROM servers AS s 
JOIN types AS t ON s.typeID = t.id
JOIN environments AS e ON s.envID = e.id
JOIN serverinstances AS si ON s.id = si.serverID
JOIN instances AS i ON si.instanceID = i.id
JOIN serverapppool AS sa ON s.id = sa.serverID
JOIN apppools AS ap ON sa.appPoolID = ap.id
WHERE computerName IS NOT NULL
```

Results for above query

```
|     ip      | type | env | instance | appPool | compName |
|_____________|______|_____|__________|_________|__________|
| 192.168.1.1 |  App | test|   com1   |   fo    |   name1  |
| 192.168.1.1 |  App | test|   com1   |   bo    |   name1  |
| 192.168.1.1 |  App | test|   com2   |   fo    |   name1  |
| 192.168.1.1 |  App | test|   com2   |   bo    |   name1  |
| 192.168.1.2 |  App | test|   com1   |   fo    |   name2  |
| 192.168.1.2 |  App | test|   com1   |   bo    |   name2  |
| 192.168.1.2 |  App | test|   com2   |   fo    |   name2  |
| 192.168.1.2 |  App | test|   com2   |   bo    |   name2  |
| 192.168.1.3 |  App | prod|   com1   |   fo    |   name3  |
| 192.168.1.4 |  App | prod|   com1   |   fo    |   name4  |
| 192.168.1.5 |  App | prod|   com1   |   bo    |   name5  |
```

These results are accurate. However I need to condense them. The goal is to make them look like the below

```
|     ip      | type | env |  instances  | appPools | compName |
|_____________|______|_____|_____________|__________|__________|
| 192.168.1.1 |  App | test| com1, com2  |  fo, bo  |   name1  |
| 192.168.1.2 |  App | test| com1, com2  |  fo, bo  |   name2  |
| 192.168.1.3 |  App | prod|    com1     |    fo    |   name3  |
| 192.168.1.4 |  App | prod|    com1     |    fo    |   name4  |
| 192.168.1.5 |  App | prod|    com1     |    bo    |   name5  |
```

I believe this can be done through the use of `GROUP_CONCAT` and as you can see in the first query, I tried some various things. But can't get it to product the needed results. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GROUP` in `GROUP_CONCAT` should tip you off - you're not actually GROUPing anything in your query, e.g. there is no `GROUP BY` clause. Since you haven't told MySQL how your data should be grouped, it's not doing ANY grouping. Hence only getting a single value out of your GROUP_CONCAT calls.

Most likely you'd want something more like

```
SELECT s.ip
etc..
etc..
GROUP BY s.ip  <---this line is missing
```

Comment: Yup! That was precisely the problem. Thanks!